# Find by some columns with latest version

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

There is table like:

```
TOOL
---------------
type
user
version.
```

For example:

```
type  | user  | version
---------------------
type1 | user1 | 1
type1 | user1 | 2
type2 | user1 | 1
type3 | user2 | 1
```

I need to select by user and get tools with different types and latest version.

Like for user1:

```
type  | user  | version
type1 | user1 | 2    
type2 | user1 | 1
```

How to do it?

Comment: [Many duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+postgresql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/J9qLM1uSy9HH5FsUrVEHX/2).

```
select
    type,
    user,
    version
from
(
    select
        *,
        row_number() over (partition by type, user order by version desc) as rnk
    from tool
) t
where rnk = 1
```

Output:

```
| type  | user  | version |
| ----- | ----- | ------- |
| type1 | user1 | 2       |
| type2 | user1 | 1       |
| type3 | user2 | 1       |
```

Comment: @zealous i need only by user | type1 | user1 | 2       |
| type2 | user1 | 1       |

Comment: @ks_on_v it is only by `user`, you have `user2` in your test data. If you only need `user1` then you can always put ` "user" = 'user1'` in `where` condition.

Comment: @zealous Great! Thanks! How to select all without rnk?

Comment: @ks_on_v what do you mean by select all?

Comment: @zealous i have another columns in table. I need Select * from. But in result i have "rnk" column. I need Select * without rnk column

Comment: @ks_on_v then select all with column names  without rnk.

Comment: @zealous could you describe how to do that?

Comment: @ks_on_v I am not getting what exactly are you asking. Above query I have provided is not getting `rnk` as a column. only selecting three columns, if you need more then add those column names one after another as shown in an example.